# Custom Label mapping pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which looks something like this:

```
ID CD
1  70
2  51
3  54
4  55
5  57
6  14
```

I want to map these labels to values like 70->1,(51,54,55)->2,57->3,else 4.
Final dataset would look something like this:

```
ID CD CD_New
1  70 1
2  51 2
3  54 2
4  55 2
5  57 3
6  14 4
```

How do achieve this in Pandas?

Comment: You're going to have to provide a [mcve]

Comment: are you trying to dynamically create these labels? or are these the only values you are going to be working with.

Comment: These are the only values I would be working with. CD is a categorical variable which I want to map to an integer so that I can further work on it

Comment: @sinha-shaurya see my answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use np.select

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_clipboard()
conditions = [df['CD']==70, df['CD'].isin([51,54,55]), df['CD']==57]
choices = [1,2,3]
df['CD_New'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=4)
df
```

Results:

```
    ID  CD  CD_New
0   1   70  1
1   2   51  2
2   3   54  2
3   4   55  2
4   5   57  3
5   6   14  4
```